# dovecot aut-worker Fatal

Tags: dovecot

I have set up a test Server with dovecot and get this error in mail.warn

```
dovecot: auth-worker: Fatal: master: service(auth-worker): child 6169 killed with signal 11
```

My dovecot.conf is the same like here: https://thomas-leister.de/mailserver-debian-stretch/#hauptkonfigurationsdatei-dovecot-conf

I found this error in google and have insert a block for auth-worker in dovecot.conf

```
service auth-worker {
    user = dovecot
    unix_listener auth-worker {
        user = dovecot
    }
}
```

But no luck with this.

Comment: Signal 11 is a segmentation fault and unlikely to be config. It's more likely to be corrupt program files or mismatched versions.

Comment: Corrupt Programm I don't hope. I have try the same Installation in three Server. Use dovecot from developer Version 2.3

Comment: I use dovecot from developer Version 2.3 and postfix from sid. I have try also from backport